# Is there a \show for catcodes?

Tags: tex-core, debugging, catcodes

In the course of attempting to out-pedant another mathematician, I wanted to `\show` the catcode of `$` to convince myself that it was a "special" character in ordinary TeX as well as LaTeX.  I was just using a "dumb tex" session (that is, I invoked `tex` from the commandline with no file) so what I wanted was to be able to type:

```
\showcatcode$
```

but that didn't work.  In the end, I did

```
\count255=\catcode`$
\showthe\count255
```

but that *just doesn't smell right*.  What's the best way to `\show` the catcode of a token?

(To be clear, the result of a `\showcatcode` should go to the terminal and the log, not in the document itself.)

Comment: I believe that `\showthe` works for any internal integer, even strange ones like `\parshape`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it's not complicated:

```
\showthe\catcode`$
```

Comment: Now that is bizarre.  I tried that and it gave me nonsense.  Yet now when I try it again, it works.  Did you invoke `M-x quantum-butterfly` again?  (I suspect that my earlier experiments messed things up so that the above didn't work, but not being used to working with `tex` on the commandline, I didn't spot it.)

Comment: I don't know what you met. (And I'm not an Emacser.) It does work for me, plain TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: Otherwise a simple `\show $` will indicate that it is the `math shift $`, whereas `\show *` (say) gives `the character *`.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: @Caramdir: Yep, I remember that I've seen it. And as a vimer, I hate emacs :)